# Simplifying $100/(50 + \sqrt{(a + sb)/sc}) $ to take inverse Laplace transform

Tags: functions, inverse-laplace

I have the following function:

$100/(50 + \sqrt{(a + sb)/sc}) $ where a, b, and c, are constants and $s=j\omega$. I have tried using inverse Laplace calculators online, but I get that there are no solutions in terms of standard functions. I have tried to simplify by hand, but I cannot get far enough to the point where I can simply use a table. How do I simplify this?

Comment: To be clear, what exactly is your question?  You have an expression. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: I want to inverse Laplace transform it into the time domain, I thought that was clear from the title of the question @Somos

Comment: $$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{100}{50+\frac{\sqrt{a+s b}}{\sqrt{s c}}}\right](t)=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } (-1)^k 50^{-k}
   a \left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^{1-\frac{k}{2}} c^{-\frac{k}{2}} k \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)^{k/2} t^{k/2} \,
   _1F_1\left(1-\frac{k}{2};2;-\frac{a t}{b}\right)$$ Answer only by Sum.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk how did you get to this point? Also, what is $F_1$?

Comment: $\, _1F_1\left(1-\frac{k}{2};2;-\frac{a t}{b}\right)$ is the Kummer confluent hypergeometric function.

Comment: Since $1/(1 + \sqrt {\alpha + 1/s})$ tends to $1/(1 + \sqrt \alpha)$, the ILT is $\delta(t)/(1 + \sqrt \alpha)$ plus an ordinary function. The ILT can be written as the convolution of ILTs of $1 - \sqrt {\alpha + 1/s}$ and $1/(1 - \alpha - 1/s)$, which have known closed forms.